# how to process an audio file using python

Tags: python, file, audio

how to process an audio file using python

Comment: What sort of processing did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Use an  [audio module](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to an audio module (I've used PyAudio before FWIW), if you want to add effects or various filters (chopping out frequencies, etc), use [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) as well; the matrix transforms there make it pretty painless to apply whatever digital filter you like.